# Background tasks not working React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

I am developping a react native app that needs to run some tasks even when the app is closed, I need to keep track of the user's position. The problem that I have is that everything is working perfectly when the app is open but  no more when it is closed.

Here is my sleep function that is called when the user press a button :

```
  function sleep() {
    //Here, I register to receive background updates 

    return Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_TAKS, {
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.BestForNavigation,
      foregroundService:{
        title  :'location service',
        text: 'tracking your location',
        notificationTitle: 'Location...',
        notificationBody: 'currently using location...'
      },
// ? A notification must display now no ? Nothing is dispaying

      deferredUpdatesDistance: 15, //every 15 meters
      deferredUpdatesInterval: 10000, //ten secodes
      pausesUpdatesAutomatically: false
    })
  };
```

And here is my background task that is in the global scope :

```
defineTask(BACKGROUND_TAKS, async ({data: {locations}, error}) => {
  if (error){
    return console.log(error)
  }

  console.log('BACKGROUND LOCATION : ', locations)
})
```

The problem is that it does not work when I exit the app. The location service stops and I do not receive any data anymore. I have tested my code on a Google Pixel emulator and on a Samsung Galaxy S20, but neither of them works. Does anyone know why it does not work?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it does not work when I exit the app

Do you exit your app or move it to background? Like the name suggest background task will work when app is still opened but sth else is displayed on your phone.

If you are moving it to background ensure that you have granted permissions for location to run in the background https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#usebackgroundpermissionsoptions

Comment: I mean when the app is in the background it stops working (I am not closing the app)